# What could be the cause for having fingerpaintview issue in my android project

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to use fingerpaintview in my android project using kotlin as the language but always encountering error

> could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.nex3zfingerpaintview on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.

i tried adding it to the app gradle dependencies and also the project gradle dependencies but still displaying same error anytime i tried to sync or rebuild the gradle

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and provide the Gradle file that is giving you this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.